# Why can't the attribute imageurl in the image tag not accept an absolute path?

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, absolute-path, imageurl

I'm using two image tags. In one the used path is relative and in the other it is absolute. The absolute path image is not shown. Here is the code:

**Expt_Image2.aspx  page**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Expt_Image2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Expt_Image2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Image
                ID="Image1"
                runat="server"
                ImageUrl="~/Image/Bluehills.jpg"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"/>
            <asp:Image
                ID="Image2"
                runat="server"
                ImageUrl="C:\Documents and Settings\Lovey\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\Expt-New\Image\Sunset.jpg"
                Height="100"
                Width="100"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Expt_Image2.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
public partial class Expt_Image2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~/Image/"));
        Image im = new Image();
        im.ImageUrl = files[1];
        im.AlternateText = files[1];
        form1.Controls.Add(im);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the rendered HTML where is it expecting the image to be located? Is this actually where the image is?

Comment: Hi Main Point is Security if any webapplication is allowed to access  the system directories other than allowed ones [folder from where application is running called root ~] then any code can delete any file , folder on server and you know there will be more than one websites being hosted on your server and server system configuration will no allow you to access anything outside of ~ and its subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

The first error that in your `Page_Load` method you get your image and store it in array. In C# indexes of items in arrays start from 0, not from 1.

Second, you must specify the virtual path to the property `ImageUrl` of the `Image` control.

It is the right `Page_Load` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles( MapPath( "~/Image/" ) );
    Image im = new Image();
    im.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + Path.GetFileName( files[ 0 ] );
    im.AlternateText = files[ 0 ];
    im.Height = 100;
    im.Width = 100;
    form1.Controls.Add( im );
}
```

Comment: First you get all image files from `Image` directory. Then you create an `Image` control for the first image in the directory and set to it the path of that first image. When you use classes from `System.IO` namespace you must give to them real paths, for example `C:\MySite\MyFolder\MyImage.jpg`. But with the ASP.NET server controls you must work with virtual paths like `~/MyFolder/MyImage.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't MapPath return the physical location of the file. In your case something like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\image

Whereas you would want the virtual path eg. http://mysite/image/image1.png

Something like this should work:

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/Image/"));
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();        

    Image im = new Image();
    im.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + files[0].Name;
    im.AlternateText = "~/Image/" + files[0].Name;
    form1.Controls.Add(im);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the application path,

```
Request.ApplicationPath + "~/Image/"
```

This will fix the problem.

One more thing. You don't need to put "~" before the path.